# Session expires on using gridviewScroll.js with IIS 7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis-7, internet-explorer-8, session-timeout

I'm trying to freeze some columns and headers in a gridview in my asp.net application. I found a help from this [site](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/)

When deployed in production server which has IIS 7 installed in it this functionality works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and IE9+. However when opened in IE8 or less, though this functionality works fine, all the session values that I've stored gets cleared and gets redirected to login page.

I'm desperately trying to find a solution for this as almost all the users who will be using this application have only IE8 installed in their machines. Does anyone have come across the same issue?

---

**UPDATE**
When I used this code in my aspx page session expired in IE8 and IE7:

```
function gridviewScroll() {
        $('#<%=grdUserResponse.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
            width: "99%",
            height: 600,
            freezesize: 2

        });
```

However when I used the following it worked fine without any issues:

```
function gridviewScroll() {
        $('#<%=grdUserResponse.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
            width: "99%",
            height: 600,
            freezesize: 2,
            arrowsize: 30,
            varrowtopimg: "Images/arrowvt.png",
            varrowbottomimg: "Images/arrowvb.png",
            harrowleftimg: "Images/arrowhl.png",
            harrowrightimg: "Images/arrowhr.png"
        });
    }
```

Don't know what the issue is!

Comment: Please add [minimal, complete, verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: problem must be some where else.i don't think jquery will clear sessions